# understanding node.js exports/include

Tags: node.js

I am having a hard time understanding how to export a file and then include it elsewhere on node.js.

Suppose I am working on a game and I want to have the variables which define an object, or more than one, for example a var enemy:

```
var enemy = {
  health: 100,
  strengh: 87
};
```

and I save it in a file vars.js.

How can one import these variables from anywhere in my project where I need them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to export them.

So `Enemy.js`:

```
var enemy = {
  health: 100,
  strengh: 87
};

exports.health = enemy.health;
exports.strength = enemy.strength;
```

And in `otherjsfile.js`:

```
var Enemy = require('Enemy.js');


//and then you can do 

console.log(Enemy.health); ///etc
```

---

#### Side point:

If the 'enemy' information is changing periodically and you want to get the newest value, you would do:

```
  Object.defineProperty(exports, "health", {
    get: function() {
      return enemy.health;
    }
  }); //instead of `exports.health = enemy.health;`

  Object.defineProperty(exports, "strengh", {
    get: function() {
      return enemy.strengh;
    }
  }); //instead of `exports.strength = enemy.strength;`
```

Comment: Your side-point is confusing and misleading.  the exported object is shared across modules.  Changing the 'health' value on it is reflected  in all modules that require it.

Comment: @broofa that has not been my experience at all. The values are not maintained. especially if you do it the way I have in the 1st part of my answer. If `enemy.health` changes, then `exports.health` does not. There is no references in javascript (that I know of)

Comment: That's because 'enemy' is a different object than 'exports'.  But if you do 'exports.health = ...' in the main module, that property is updated everywhere.  I strongly suggest you do some more reading about how modules work - in fact, implementing a module loader would probably be a very educational exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can export from vars.js doing

```
module.exports = {
  health: 100,
  strengh: 87
};
```

or

```
var enemy = {
  health: 100,
  strengh: 87
};

module.exports = enemy;
```

And import using require:

```
var enemy = require('./path/to/vars');
```

Answer (score 0):

in file.js:

```
module.exports = {
  health: 100,
  strengh: 87
}
```

in other files:

```
var enemy = require('./file'); // (or whatever the relative path to your file is
```

[More info here.](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules)

Comment: Where did `module.exports` come from? isn't it just `exports`?

Comment: `module.exports` is available to all modules, and allows you to redefine what object is exported by the module .vs. using the default `exports` module you get.  It's often a simpler mechanism for exporting something in-bulk instead of hanging individual properties off `exports.  (note, too, that it also allows you to export a function, string or other non-Object property should you choose to do that.)

Comment: I have exported functions and objects with just plain `export`.... I do not see the difference.

Comment: @neal - not enough room here to go into more detail.  suffice it to say that you'll find some nice uses for it when you start creating sufficiently complex module dependencies.

Comment: I have... and I had to fall back to the 2nd part of what I put into my answer, if there was easier way, I would like to learn it...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20760/discussion-between-broofa-and-neal)